# Change background follow action form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change background follow the action of form1. So I tried with the below code, but it did not work. please help

```
.bgmain1 {
    background-image: url(sdadsdadas);
    background-size: 100%;
}

.bgmain2 {
    background-image: none;
}


if($('from1').action == '/* url */') {
    $('body').removeClass().addClass("bgmain2");
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass().addClass('bgmain1');
};
```

Comment: can you please include your html?

Comment: `$('from1').action` causes some issues, most likely your HTML doesn't contain a tag named `from1`, and when that is fixed, the returned jQuery object doesn't have `action` property.

Comment: Thanks Teemu. I fixed with '.form1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, hope it helps, use `attr('action')` to get action url

```js
if($('.form1').attr('action')=='action.php')
   $('.form1').addClass('bgmain1')
else
    $('.form1').removeClass('bgmain1')
```

```css
.bgmain1 {
    background:red;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action.php" class="form1">
  <input>
  <input>
</form>
<br>
```